# Charts widget is not working in Backpack 5 Pro+ Laravel 9

Tags: laravel-backpack

Following the steps in the doc (https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/5.x/base-widgets#chart-pro).
1-Installed the Chart Library
2- Created the Chart controller and added a chart. Can see the jason at route: "admin/charts/weekly-users"
3- Added the widget in the dashboard blade page

The Dashboard page is emitting @loadScriptOnce($path) right at the bottom of the page.....and the console is saying "Chart is not defined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `composer update digitallyhappy/assets` should fix it for you - let me know.

Background: there's a bug in `spatie/laravel-permission:5.5.1` that broke other packages using Blade directives. Waiting for [the PR](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission/pull/2048) to get merged. But we've also pushed a fix on our end, last night, that should prevent the interference. Hence my recommendation to get the latest version of `digitallyhappy/assets`.

Alternatively, you can lock `spatie/laravel-permission` to 5.5.0.